# Websocket connection fine with public ip address, but fails with host-domain name

Tags: node.js, websocket, public, portforwarding

In summary I'm trying to connect to a demo node.js websocket server which I have running on my machine. Using my public ip address works, but from my public hostname (provided from noip.com) eg. `example.ddns.net`, it fails.

Details:

- I have a node.js websocket server running on my local machine listening to port 8010.
- To ensure my router has port 8010 open and forwarding correctly, I am able to connect to it successfully via `ws://public-ip-address:8010`
- But when I try to connect with `ws://example.ddns.net:8010` it fails.
- I use https://www.noip.com/ to map my public-ip-address to a hostname, eg. example.ddns.net => my-public-ip-address.
- I can successfully connect to my public hostname with http://, just not ws://.

Example: (using fake dns and ip)

```
> var ws = new WebSocket('ws://example.ddns.net:8010')
> 'WebSocket connection to 'ws://example.ddns.net:8010/' failed: 
(anonymous) @ VM18:1'

> var ws = new WebSocket('ws://public-ip-address:8010')
> (connected)
```

To note:

- I've checked that my public-ip-address is correct in the mapping to hostname via noip.com (to get public ip I use `https://api.ipify.org/`)
- I'm using insecure websockets to remove any potential ssl causes
- I have also tried secure wss sockets and get the same fail if using my hostname url

My question is how can I successfully establish a websocket using my hostname in the url, and why does it work if using my public IP address? Perhaps the port number is mangled when going through noip.com?

Any thoughts really appreciated and many thanks in advance,
Isaac

Comment: As an experiment, you could try adding a mapping to your **hosts** file and see if it resolves the problem.

Comment: A possible answer to my question is that it may be due to my ISP using a double NAT system along with me not having a static IP. 

Further discussion here: [link](https://community.blynk.cc/t/local-server-no-ip/39944/4)